# Android Custom marker icon

Tags: android, marker

I'm working on application with Google maps so i want to define a custom marker for each custom place, For example (gas station- Hotel- Hospital.. ) ! i have a overlays class with the latitude and longitude of many places and i want just how to give a custom icon!

Answer (score 89):

With the new Maps Api Setting the Icon for a [Marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker) is done with the following Code:

```
MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.icon_location));
```

The icon can not be changed after a Marker was created. To change an icon remove the marker and readd it with a new image.

Answer (score 1):

with the APi v2, you can do `(markerObject).setIcon(BitmapDescriptor)` to change/set the marker image.

Answer (score 0):

[`OverlayItem.setMarker`](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/OverlayItem.html#setMarker(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)) seems like the method you're looking for.

Note that there is (or used to be) [a gotcha](http://developmentality.wordpress.com/2009/10/16/android-overlayitemsetmarkerdrawable-icon/) you need to be aware of; you first need to use `Drawable.setBounds` to set the visible boundaries of the drawable before it can be rendered properly. Some fiddling might be needed to get it to centre; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6173388/googlemaps-custom-itemizedoverlay-and-overlayitem-the-correct-way-to-show-diff).