# How to over lay images on the googlemaps

Tags: android, google-maps, android-sdcard

I am some images on the SD card. I have also save their longitude and latitude ..Now i want to overlay all these images on the Google map as thumbnail image..and when i click on any thumbnail image it will move to the next activity as show the full picture.I can over lay only one image...and its code is this.....

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.googlemap);
        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    //  imm=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.Google_Img_View);
        mapView.setSatellite(true);
        b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.googleImageDone);
        b.setOnClickListener(this);
        Intent i = getIntent();
        //Parcelable myParcelableObject = (Parcelable) i.getParcelableExtra("name_of_extra");
        bit = (Bitmap) getIntent().getParcelableExtra("Map");
        //imm.setImageBitmap(bit);
        String id = i.getStringExtra("lon");
        String name = i.getStringExtra("long");
//      mapView.setTraffic(true);

        mc = mapView.getController();
        String coordinates[] = {id,name};
        double lat = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[0]);
        double lng = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[1]);
        pp = new GeoPoint((int) (lat * 1E6),    (int) (lng * 1E6));
        mc.animateTo(pp);
        mc.setZoom(19);

        MapOverlay mapOverlay = new MapOverlay();
    List<Overlay> listOfOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
        listOfOverlays.clear();
        listOfOverlays.add(mapOverlay);
    }

    private class MapOverlay extends Overlay
    {

        @Override
        public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView,
                boolean shadow, long when)
        {
            super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);
            Point screenPts = new Point();
            //---translate the GeoPoint to screen pixels---
            mapView.getProjection().toPixels(pp, screenPts);
            //---convert the gif image into bmp         
    //      Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
    //              getResources(), R.drawable.e);
            //---add the marker---
            canvas.drawBitmap(bit, screenPts.x, screenPts.y-50, null);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event, MapView mapView)
        {
            if (event.getAction() == 1) 
            {
                GeoPoint p = mapView.getProjection().fromPixels(
                        (int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY());
                st1=p.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6+"";
                st2=p.getLongitudeE6() /1E6+"";

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Location: "+
                        p.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6 + "," + p.getLongitudeE6() /1E6 ,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please post what you have tried.

Comment: i can overlay only one image.

Comment: i have posted my code there

Comment: You should try using Maps API v2 and it's `GroundOverlay`s, as v1 of the API will soon be deprecated. You can create the overlays from `Bitmap`s using `BitmapDescriptor`.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class -

```
public class HelloItemizedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> {
private ArrayList<OverlayItem> mOverlays = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
private Context mContext;

public HelloItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, Context context) {
    super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
    mContext = context;
}

public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay) {
    mOverlays.add(overlay);
    populate();
}

@Override
protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
    return mOverlays.get(i);
}

@Override
public int size() {
    return mOverlays.size();
}

@Override
protected boolean onTap(int index) {
    OverlayItem item = mOverlays.get(index);
    AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
    dialog.setTitle(item.getTitle());
    dialog.setMessage(item.getSnippet());
    dialog.show();
    return true;
}
```

Create one more class for Latitute and Longitude conversion-

```
public class LatLonPoint extends GeoPoint {
public LatLonPoint(double latitude, double longitude) {
    super((int) (latitude * 1E6), (int) (longitude * 1E6));
}
}
```

And then in your main activity -

```
mMapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mv);
    mMapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mMapView.getOverlays();
    Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(
            R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    HelloItemizedOverlay itemizedoverlay = new HelloItemizedOverlay(
            drawable, this);
    GeoPoint point = new LatLonPoint(12.917745600000000000,
            77.623788300000000000);
    OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point, "Bangalore!",
            "I'm in Silkboard!");

    GeoPoint point2 = new LatLonPoint(12.8511803, 77.6635172);
    OverlayItem overlayitem2 = new OverlayItem(point2, "Bangalore!",
            "India, Somewhere!");
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem2);
    mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);
```

To read images from SDcard -

```
Resources res = getResources();
Bitmap bitmapICON = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("PATH OF THE IMAGE");
BitmapDrawable bdICON = new BitmapDrawable(res, bitmapICON);
```

Comment: you are passing only one drawable from in the helloitemizedoverlay constructor while i need to get all the images from the sdcard..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6173388/googlemaps-custom-itemizedoverlay-and-overlayitem-the-correct-way-to-show-diff

Comment: I am stuck on that..My images are from sdcard they are not in drawable..But here you are getting image from Drawable...how to over come that...

Comment: i have executed your code with simple drawable..But still it didn't show any over lay image on the map...